# mod_rewrite-rule not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have domainname.(de|at|ch|com|net|...) all going into Document_Root. Now I want /forum/ in every tld expect at|ch|de to redirect to /forum_eng/.

The following Rewrite-Rules from [Document_Root]/.htaccess doesn't work. It shows the default /forum/ folder. I don't know why.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# https redirects, www-redirects and other stuff

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainname\.(?!(de|ch|at))[a-z]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum(/.*)?(\?.*)?$ /forum_eng$1$2 [L]
```

Does anybody know, what I do wrong? On [this htaccess-simulator](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), it works.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how it doesn't work?  What actually happens?

Comment: @Sildoreth It shows the /forum/-folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for just asking and answering now!

The directory [Document_Root]/forum/ already existed and there was a .htaccess in it, so the .htaccess in the Document_Root was skipped.